# Why am I seeing "KeyError: 'rating_count_total' " in this code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to iterate through two series  which are derived from ios_mod2_apps

```
   list_of_genre = ios_mod2_apps['prime_genre'].unique()
   list_of_app = ios_mod2_apps['track_name']
```

Then I am iterating through the two series and run the following code inside the two for loops

```
app_rating_percentage[app] = ios_mod2_apps['rating_count_total'][ios_mod2_apps['track_name']==app].sum() /(ios_mod2_apps['rating_count_tot'][ios_mod2_apps['prime_genre']==genre].sum())
```

Basically the code above calculates the sum of the series of 'rating_count_total' which has the track_name as the app valuable in that iteration.

When I ran this code I get the error

> KeyError: 'rating_count_total'

I have tried to understand this error but could not. I would use some help if someone have a clue of what is wrong.

Full code

```
#initiating an empty dictionary to take the values that will be created on the for loops
    app_rating_percentage = {}


#create a list of unique genres
#create a list of apps these two lists will be used to iterate 
list_of_genre = ios_mod2_apps['prime_genre'].unique()
list_of_app = ios_mod2_apps['track_name']

#iterate using the two above lists, and calculate the rating_count_total(of that app) devide by the sum of rating_count_total in that genre

for genre in list_of_genre:
     for app in list_of_app:
        app_rating_percentage[app] = ios_mod2_apps['rating_count_total'][ios_mod2_apps['track_name']==app].sum() /(ios_mod2_apps['rating_count_tot'][ios_mod2_apps['prime_genre']==genre].sum())
    
app_rating_percentage
```

Comment: `KeyError` means the column you're trying to index on does not exist. Have you checked the output of `ios_mod2_apps.columns` to see if the column label exists on the df?

Comment: Thank you that was the problem.

Index(['id', 'track_name', 'size_bytes', 'currency', 'price',
       **'rating_count_tot'**, 'rating_count_ver', 'user_rating',
       'user_rating_ver', 'cont_rating', 'prime_genre'],
      dtype='object')